# Quick Resistance Calculation Check

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors

In the following circuit, I have to calculate the resistance between AB :

[image]

thus \$R_{AB} = 2 + (4 || (9 + (6 || (2 + 6 || (10 + 3 || 6)))))\$.

This is the equivalent circuit that I imagined :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxCrMg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is my equivalent circuit and calculation correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Your equivalent circuit and the formula for \$R_{AB}\$ you derived is correct.

We can easily check if the circuits are equivalent in the CircuitLab simulator built into the question and answer editor on this site:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fClZBB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The two circuits that should have equal resistances are put in one arm of a bridge, two identical resistors in another arm, and a null voltmeter between the two arms. We read out 0V, so the two circuits indeed have the same resistance.

Comment: Infinite gratitude :)